# Algorithm to split strings in array to create a menu and submenus data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, algorithm

I've a Javascript array of strings like:

```
var array = [{
  string: 'path1/path2/path3'
}, {
  string: 'path1/path4/path5'
}, {
  string: 'path1/path2/path6'
}, {
  string: 'path10/path7'
}, {
  string: 'path10/path8/path9'
}];
```

and I need to create a data model structured like this:

```
-- path1
  -- path2
    -- path3
    -- path6
  -- path4
    -- path5
-- path10
  -- path7
  -- path8
    -- path9
```

How can I achive this? Do you have any advice? Thank you

Edit:

I was thinking something like:

```
var paths = {
  children = [
    { 
     name: "path1"
     children: [
      { 
       name: "path2", 
       children: [
        { 
         name: "path3", 
         children: []
        }]
      },
      {
       name: "path4", 
       children: [
        { 
         name: "path5", 
         children: []
        }]
      }
    }
   ],
   .......
};
```

Comment: please add the type of the wanted result - is it a data structure (object/array/tree), a HTML structure or something else? what have you tried, what does not work?

Comment: I want that the result is an object in order to create then the HTML menu.
I'm trying to find a smart approach to create the object.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```js
var array = [{
  string: 'path1/path2/path3'
}, {
  string: 'path1/path4/path5'
}, {
  string: 'path1/path2/path6'
}, {
  string: 'path10/path7'
}, {
  string: 'path10/path8/path9'
}];

let tree = {};

for (let {string} of array) {
    let t = tree;
    for (let c of string.split('/'))
        t = t[c] || (t[c] = {});
}

console.log(tree);
```

Comment: Thank you @georg this is something to start but it's not very good to use it inside the HTML.

Comment: Great solution!